# How can I count unique values in a table in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a table "stock" which consists of many package_ids

```
package_id = 1  
package_id = 3  
package_id = 2  
package_id = 3  
package_id = 3  
package_id = 4  
package_id = 2
```

What is the most elegant way to:

- count each unique package_id in the db, e.g.: package_id 1 = one time
  in the db; package_id 2 = two times in the db; package_id 3 = three
  times in the DB ...
- echo the top 3 of package IDs afterwards

I have tried this step by step:

- counting each single package_id (Stock.where(:package_id => 1).count)
- putting that all in an array
- and sort that array from high to low (only first 3 items)

This however does not seems to be an effective path though.

Comment: you mean Stock.where(:package_id => 1).distinct ?

Comment: no. I want the query to check on each package_id in the DB. so ideally I won't ask the DB for each single package_id - that would be the way I tried already.

Comment: How about `Stock.group(:package_id).count`. It will return a hash having package_id as a key and the count as a value. Give it a try and see if it is what you want.

Comment: exactly what I was looking for! grab your reputation for the right answer my friend :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about:

```
Stock.group(:package_id).count
```

It will return a hash having package_id as a key and the count as a value:

```
{ package_id1: count1, package_id2: count2 ....}
```

Answer (score 5):

Try with this to get the 'Top 3':

```
Stock.select('package_id, count(*) as c').group(:package_id).order('c DESC').limit(3)
```